# Is there a way to change Parent Table name with out changing its reference name in child table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a console application to encrypt large sql tables. As part of encryption i am copying data to temp table, once encryption is complete I am renaming source table as backup table and temp table as Source table. when i am renaming source table to backup table. since renaming table only changes object description but not object Id, source table reference in child table is changing to backup table. Is there a way to rename table with out effecting references. As per requirements,I should not drop any tables.

Comment: Are you working with SQL Server?

Comment: yes. I am working with sql server. i ma using "sp_rename" to rename my tables

Comment: Do you know about [Transparent Data Encyption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-2017) built in SQL Server?